# Position of view relative to parent

Tags: android, android-layout, coordinates

I have a created a custom View with Android 5.1 as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/task_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context="com.task.TaskActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/task_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#e4e4e4"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#000000" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/task_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/task_header"
        android:gravity="center">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/myRectangleView"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="316dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="316dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I would like to get the x and y positions of the `myRectangleView`. I can do it as follows:

```
    View rectangleView = findViewById(R.id.myRectangleView);
    rectangleView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    int x = location[0];
    int y = location[1];
```

The problem is that this gives me the absolute position on the screen but I want the position relative to the `task_header`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using just getX(), getY() or getLocalVisibleRect(Rect r)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try traversing "upwards" from each view, summing each containers position in the process:

```
/** Returns array of views [x, y] position relative to parent **/
public static int[] getPositionInParent(ViewGroup parent, View view){
    int relativePosition[] = {view.getLeft(), view.getTop()};
    ViewGroup currentParent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    while (currentParent != parent){
        relativePosition[0] += currentParent.getLeft();
        relativePosition[1] += currentParent.getTop();
        currentParent = (ViewGroup) currentParent.getParent();
    }
    return relativePosition;
}
```

This has no error handling, but should work even in more nested layouts.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a simple one in Kotlin. This will work if you know the immediate parent of the child parameter view.

```
        fun getPositionInParent(parent: ViewGroup, child: View): IntArray {
            val relativePosition = intArrayOf(child.left, child.top)
            val positionPreview = intArrayOf(1, 2)
            val positionFrame = intArrayOf(1, 2)
            parent.getLocationInWindow(positionPreview)
            child.getLocationInWindow(positionFrame)

            relativePosition[0] = positionFrame[0] - positionPreview[0]
            relativePosition[1] = positionFrame[1] - positionPreview[1]
            return relativePosition
        }
```